# jQuery $.data order is not correct for dropdown list option

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I've below HTML,

```
<table id="_GroupsTable">
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th style="width: 90%;">
         City
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10%;">
         Del
      </th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select id="_SkillsDropDownList0" name="_SkillsDropDownList0">
            <option value="1">All Skills</option>
            <option value="2">&nbsp;Web App</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="5">&nbsp;&nbsp;MVC</option>
            <option value="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;jQuery</option>
            <option value="16">&nbsp;&nbsp;HTML</option>
            <option value="4">&nbsp;&nbsp;CSS</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
         <input id="_GroupsRolesCheckbox0" type="checkbox">
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
<table>
```

When I tried to read value with below code I'm not getting the values in proper order.

```
var jdata = $("#_GroupsTable")[0];
var kvpGroups = $.data(jdata, "groupsKvp");
```

I'm expecting the values in 1 = All Skills, 2 = Web App, 3= jQuery.. basically the same order where values are appearing in the dropdown, however, I'm NOT getting in the same order. Any pointer at the right directions will be appreciated.

Comment: What's populating that `$.data()` in the first place?  It's not populated automatically by jQuery all by itself.

Comment: Why are you using `$.data()` and not `$("#_GroupsTable").data("groupsKvp")`?

Comment: by using $("#_GroupsTable").data("groupsKvp") did not changed the result.. :( :(